# vglobal with parameter in function, to filter textfile into temporary file

Tags: vim, filter, scripting

I've got a textfile which I want to filter for a pattern, to get a quick overview. My normal approach in vim is to filter via `:v/pattern/d`. This works fine, but If I save the file accidentally, after I did the filtering, I loose the not filtered information.

To avoid this, I search for a solution where the orginal textfile cannot be destroy by accident.

My current solution is a function where I read the textile into a temporary file and run the filter on this file. But the function does not work if I try to search something like `^linestart`. Furthermore I want to highlight the search pattern, which as well does not work as expected.

Here is my function in vimscript:

```
function! FilterJournal(pattern)
    :exe 'e ~/tempfile'
    " delete all existing lines
    :1,$d
    :exe 'r ~/journal.txt'
    :exe 'silent v/ ' . a:pattern . '/d'
    " to highlight the search pattern
    :exe 'silent / ' . a:pattern  

endfunction
:command! -nargs=1 Fijo :call FilterJournal("<args>")
```

When I run the command: `Fijo foo` I get the result, but the highlightning does not work.

When I run the command: `Fijo ^foo` I get some error messages and the tempfile is empty:

```
Error during execution of "function FilterJournal":
Line 6: 
E486: Pattern not found: ^foo
```

**How can I filter my textfile without destroy it by accident *or* get my function to work?**

Comment: "If I save the file accidentally, after I did the filtering, I loose the not filtered information" Can't you just do `u`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this based on your function. Please note that

- The space in `v/`  causes `E486: Pattern not found`
- I tried `set hlsearch` but it did not work in this case. However, `:match` works well for highlighting in the current buffer
- Leading `:` is not necessary

```
function! FilterJournal(pattern)
    exe 'e ~/tempfile'
    " delete all existing lines
    1,$d
    exe 'r ~/journal.txt'
    exe 'v/' . a:pattern . '/d'

    " to highlight the search pattern
    exe 'match Search /' . a:pattern . '/'
endfunction

:command! -nargs=1 Fijo :call FilterJournal("<args>")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want "to get a quick overview", you could simply do:

```
:g/pattern
```

which prints the matching lines without affecting the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it yanks the matched lines and show it in a vsplit buffer:

```
function! FilterIt(pat)
    call setreg('x', '')
    call setreg('/', a:pat)
    exec 'g/'.a:pat.'/y X'
    exec 'vsp /tmp/t'       
    exec 'norm! ggVG"xp'
endfunction

:command! -nargs=1 Fijo :call FilterIt("<args>")
```